# Charge a conductor dome indefinitely frome the inside

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, potential-energy

Suppose we have a **hollow conducting dome with a small hole** from which you can touch the inner surface with, let say, a conducting rod. I make sure that the dome is completely uncharged: it has the same voltage of the ground now. I charge the rod with a power supply of a few KiloVolt (with respect to the ground). As i bring the rod near the outer surface of the dome the electric field polarize the dome and as i touch, the dome get charged. Now the dome has a voltage different from the ground. I can repeat the process until the dome and the rod reach the same voltage of the power supply. So i can't charge  the dome indefinitely from the outside. Then i go to the inside of the dome where the inner surface is neutral. Since there must be en electric field in the cavity (Gauss law) **there must be a potential difference between the rod and the inner surface**, then when i touch the inner surface i charge the dome, and the charge redistributes on the outer surface. Now i can repeat the process indefinitely because the inner surface will always be neutral and will always have a lower potential then the charged rod.

Now my question is: Since the dome is a conductor **is also an equipotential**, thereby when i get the dome charged till a few KiloVolt (same of power supply) i have rod, outer surface, inside of the conductor dome and inner surface **with the same voltage** (with respect to the ground).**Thereby i shouldn't have any electric field when i put the charged rod inside the dome**. Still there must be an electric field (gauss law). What am i missing?

**-Edit-**

Here's a a diagram:[image]

The diagram shows the Dome and the rod with their electric potential before and after i put the rod inside the dome. The *R*,*D*,*P* stand for rod, dome and power supply respectively.

**-Edit-**

I think i got the problem: it was a misunderstanding of what the electric potential is. When we move the charged rod but stay outside the dome the potential of the rod will always remain constant, but when we put it inside the dome its potential will increase. Let set the voltage at infinity equals to zero and assume the charged dome and the charged rod has the same electric potential $V_P$. **This means** that if we take a positive test charge $q$, the work required to move the test charge near the surface of the dome is the same of that required to move it near the surface of the rod and is in magnitude $qV_P$. Now if i put the charged rod inside the dome its potential will increase and there will be en electric field as shown in the diagram. The increment of the potential is due to the increment of work we must do in order to bring the test charge $q$ from the outer surface of the dome to the inside, near the surface of the rod. Therefore the electric potential of the rod (wich is in magnitude work per unit charge) must increase.

Comment: A diagram(s) would greatly help here

Comment: Sure. I think i got what i was missing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely you can do this. It is how a [Van-de-Graaff generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator) works.  There is an energy cost to carrying the charges *to* the dome, so you are not getting enegy fro free, but once inside you can deposit the charge onto the dome and so build up enough charge on the dome, until the voltage is sufficiently high that a long spark occurs and discharges it.

Comment: Exacly, my question is about the van der graaf generator though i didn't mention it. I got your answer but i feel something is still missing. I think the point is: what is the difference of touching the dome from inside and from outside? Both the inside and outer surface have the same potential therefore i conclude that if i can't charge anymore from the outside then i can't charge anymore from the inside as well. I know there is something wrong but i don't get it.

Comment: Same potential *yes*, same electric field *no*. It's the electric field due to the charge on the rod  that makes the charges leave the rod for the inside of the sphere.  The charges on the rod inside the sphere are at a slightly higher potential than the inside (and hence the outside) of the sphere because of the field around the rod.